# Ajax Drop Down extender always expand associated panel in Ajax Tab Control at page load

Tags: asp.net-ajax, dropdownextender

I use drop down extender in tab container and it is always expand at page load. It only collapse after clicking at text box. It is working fine at outside of the tab container and it is happening only with latest browsers.

How can I make to collapse the drop down extender at every page load?
I need to collapse it manually at page load event?

Please advise me what I am wrong and how can it collapse at code behind or at javascript?

I am using .Net 2.0 Ajax extension with vs 2005.

Below is my code.

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel1">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <ajaxToolkit:DropDownExtender ID="DropDownExtender1"             DropDownControlID="ListBox1"   runat="server" 
                TargetControlID="TextBox1">
                </ajaxToolkit:DropDownExtender>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px">
                    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:ListBox></asp:Panel>
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                </asp:ScriptManager>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel2">
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel3" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel3">
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <ajaxToolkit:DropDownExtender ID="DropDownExtender2" DropDownControlID="ListBox2" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox2">
                </ajaxToolkit:DropDownExtender>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px">
                    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:ListBox></asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by setting visibility:hidden in the CSS for the control that corresponds to your listbox.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a panel as DropDownControlID. I tried "visibility:hidden" but the space was still used (blank space instead of my panel).
I switched to the style "display:none" (on my panel) and it was perfect. Really invisible at load.

Answer (score 0):

i set **visibility hidden** in asp:Pane and it works fine for me

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCustomerLookupShipRecieving" Width="350px" OnTextChanged="OnTextChanged" autocomplete="off" Height="20px"></asp:TextBox>
  <ajaxToolkit:DropDownExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCustomerLookupShipRecieving" DropDownControlID="DropDownListPanel1" ID="DropDownExtender2" HighlightBackColor="WindowFrame" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" />
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="DropDownListPanel1" Style="z-index: 99999;**visibility:hidden**;">
     <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lstCustomerLookupShipRecieving"
      DataTextField="CustomerName" DataValueField="CustomerId" AutoPostBack="True"                                       
      OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnCustomerSelectedChangedShipReceiving" Rows="20" Width="365px" CssClass="DropDownListBoxStyle" ></asp:ListBox>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCustomerLookupShipRecieving" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="CustomerName"          
       DataValueField="CustomerId" Height="26px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnCustomerSelectedChanged" ToolTip="Customers List" Width="30px" Visible="False">
      </asp:DropDownList>
```